# Different frequency responses for series RLC series circuit using Multisim vs. MATLAB

Tags: filter, passive-networks, matlab

I have been trying to simulate the following RLC circuit:

[image]

When I simulated in Multisim Live I obtained the following frequency response, which I expected based on the values I used to calculate resistance, capacitance, and inductance.

[image]

However, when I simulate the same circuit in MATLAB, I get the following frequency response:

[image]

I am unsure why this difference is occurring. I assume it has something to do with the transfer function that I used to plot it, but I can't figure out where I might have gone wrong. Here is my code; please tell me what I missed.

```
L=100e-3; %define the capcitance value for the filters
R1=180; %define the resistance values for bandpass filters
C1=2.09341e-7; %define c for lowmid bandpass


% Plot the frequency response
figure
freqs([C1*R1 0], [C1*L, C1*R1, 1]);
title('lowMid')
```

Answer (score 2):

Multisim frequency is plotted in Hertz, MATLAB is plotted in rads per second, that’s going to be part of the problem. 1000 Hz should be 6283 rad/s so there’s still a discrepancy, not sure why and I don’t have either software so I can’t test it. It could be a math error such as rounding, or maybe some built-in parasitics in Multisim.